# How to stop my activity from opening another instance in another application from share menu?

Tags: java, android, oncreate, onnewintent

I have my application that allows other apps that can share files to select it on the share menu, open the application up and "transfer" the files over to my app.

My problem is when they select my application from the share menu (as example, in gallery, after selecting several photos, they choose to share with my app) the login activity gets opened inside the gallery application

Please note that i have tried this process works on older devices and it worked but not for a newer device.

This is my manifest.xml

```
<application
    android:name="com.Application"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:fullBackupContent="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:mimeType="*/*"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".login.LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateVisible">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I have two activities for this app, login and Main, Main will be loaded up if login is successful.

I have tried with different kinds of launcherMode settings but nothing has stopped the instance from being created in gallery

This is from my login Activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    receivedIntent = getIntent();
    //set orientation
    setRequestedOrientation(isPhone() ? ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT : ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    if (intent != null && intent.getAction() != null && (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND) || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE))){
        finish();
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

The problem is, on the older device the onNewIntent method gets called as expected, but on the newer device it just ignores the launcherMode and creates the new instance and runs onCreate()

Any ideas on how to get the application to "force" launch itself when called from a share menu?

Current Testing devices - Samsung mobile Android 8.0, API 26 - not working
                          Samsung Tablet Android 7.1.1, API 25 - working as expected

Comment: was `LoginActivity#onDestroy` called?

Comment: i will have a look now

Comment: no, it simply pauses the activity when it goes into the background and begins a new one when selected on the share menu

Comment: ok, so what `android:launchMode` you used?

Comment: android:launchMode="singleInstance", i have also tried singleTop and singleTask with no resolution

Comment: it works as expected on Android 7.1.1 API 25, but when used on Android 8.0.0, API 26 it has this problem, (the two devices i'm testing on at the moment)

Comment: I will see either My application and then gallery (when you click on gallery it contains my login activity), or just gallery which contains my login activity

Answer (score 0):

All your issue is about the permissions, 
Old devices below kitkat(4.4.2) does not required permissions of file but in new devices required permissions for access the file data(ie. gallery and others).
You have to grant permission programmatically,

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            arrPerm.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }

        if (!arrPerm.isEmpty()) {
            String[] permissions = new String[arrPerm.size()];
            permissions = arrPerm.toArray(permissions);
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissions, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
        } 
    }
```

After Permission Granted you can do your operation:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 19) {
                    if (isPermissionGranted()) {
                        //Do your Task of gallery
                    } 
                }
```

Or alternate way, you can use library directly:
https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions

Comment: I have edited the question to show which devices i am testing on, both are above the required API for permission requests and i believe i am not using any code at this time that requires permissions

Comment: @Brandon all the devices are above the version 4.4.2, so that you must have to write code for permission, because you are using the file manager and SD card content, for testing you can give them permission manually, Setting>app>allow permission ....but before that you have make sure that permission are declared in AndroidManifest.xml .if this process works for you then write code for permissions ..I suggest you to use library that's is easy enough to use..but code manually recommend

Comment: If the application was trying to access without permission then it would throw a securityException, which it is not, and as it is able to perform the expected actions on other devices without those permissions being requested i don't believe this is a permissions issue

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging into other apps on the device and found this issue is only occurring when sharing images from the application "Gallery" otherwise the code works as expected, so i believe this could be an issue with Gallery itself or is expected behavior for the Gallery application.